# Setup Spring boot health actuator in spring framework app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I currently have a spring app (not spring boot) with no spring-web or spring-mvc. I want to make use of the spring boot actuator (health) to monitor the health of my app. In order to do so I need to have a running server I believe ?
I therefore added following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this config class

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class , HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class ActuatorConfig {
}
```

I am a little lost still and trying to find my way. When I try run the app I get the following error:

```
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout): 2023-04-18 14:46:42.550 +0800 [main] [ERROR] c.e.f.FxRatePublisherBootstrap - Exception caught in bootstrapping, shutting down...
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout): org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at com.eclipseoptions.fxratepublisher.FxRatePublisherBootstrap.main(FxRatePublisherBootstrap.java:25)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout): Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     ... 14 common frames omitted
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:591)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
fx-rate-publisher.test(stdout):     ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Any idea how I can setup a `ServletContext` and start the tomcat server and expose the health actuator endpoint ?

Comment: Just adding a bunch of dependencies to your app won't automatically make it work. You have to mimic the start of Spring Boot in your application, start the server yourself, registere your context with it etc. Instead of doing that I would suggest to just make it a proper Spring Boot application.

Comment: If you dont mind may I ask what are the requirements/setup needed for adding spring boot actuators to a spring framework app with no spring-web or spring-mvc. I can look more deeply into each step and try to do it. Making it a spring boot app might not be possible.

Comment: If you can add the dependencies, and basically do what Spring Boot does you can also make it a Spring Boot application. As I stated in my previous comment is you need to start tomcat, register your applicatio context and servlet with it.

Comment: You can also get metrics through JMX so you don't necessarily need a web server. Not sure what it is you are looking for and how you intend to monitor the health.

Comment: I want to expose a REST endpoint which will be called by another app/service to monitor the health of my app